# Angular js: how to refresh data from another page using routeprovider

Tags: javascript, angular, controller, angular-ui-router, single-page-application

i'm using Angular Js with an example similar to this one

https://www.w3schools.com/angular/tryit.asp?filename=try_ng_routing_provider

My question is: i click, for example, Main, and in a section of my page i see the data contained in main.htm

in my example my main file is not a html file, it's a file in which data change, depending what i click in my home page. i send data to this main file, the data change in this file and then i can see them in a part of my page. when i make the first call to main there is no problem it works, but when i make the other calls, the data in my page are the same of the first call, as if the other calls don't work.

i did the first call to main, it works, i expected that the other calls work and i can see new data in my page  `<script> var app = angular.module("myApp", ["ngRoute"]); app.config(function($routeProvider) { $routeProvider .when("/order", { //here it opens the file associated templateUrl : "order...", controller : "theCtrl" }) }); app.controller("theCtrl", function ($scope) { }); </script>`in the modal i opened, i can manipulate the data deciding what i need. when i change data in the modal, i pass the data to the file order... with this code `$("#my_div").load("order...?data=...` when i close the modal, in a part of my main page i can see the code contained in the file order... so it's ok, it works. When i open a new modal in my main page and i make another order, manipulating the data in the modal, sending data to file order... like i did the first time, i close the modal but in my main page i see the code i choosed the first time.   How can i refresh (i don't know if it's correct saying "refresh") data so that i can see a new order in a part of my main page (the content of angular view) ? –

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.